# SQLite-Net Extension both one-to-one and one-to-many relationships between two entities

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I am using SQLite-Net PCL together with SQLite-Net extensions for the development of an application using Xamarin.

In my model I have two entities, let us call them A and B, that are connected by both a one-to-one and a one-to-many relationships. For instance, A has a one-to-one relationship with B, and A has also a one-to-many relationship with B.

Is it possible to express such behaviour with SQLite-Net extensions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, but you have to explicitly declare the foreign keys and inverse properties in the relationship attribute, because otherwise the library may get the wrong foreign key for the relationship.

```cs
    public class ClassA
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [OneToMany("O2MClassAKey", "BObjectsInverse")]
        public List<ClassB> BObjects { get; set; }

        [OneToOne("O2OClassAKey", "BObjectInverse")]
        public ClassB BObject { get; set; }

        // Other properties
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
        
    public class ClassB
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof (ClassA))]
        public int O2MClassAKey { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof (ClassA))]
        public int O2OClassAKey { get; set; }

        // Inverse relationships, these are optional
        [ManyToOne("O2MClassAKey", "BObjects")]
        public ClassA BObjectsInverse { get; set; }
        [OneToOne("O2OClassAKey", "BObject")]
        public ClassA BObjectInverse { get; set; }

        // Other properties
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }
```

Please note that the foreign key `O2OClassAKey` for the `OneToOne` relationship can be declared in any of the classes.

If you don't need inverse properties, you can skip them in the relationship attribute:

```cs
    public class ClassA
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [OneToMany("O2MClassAKey")]
        public List<ClassB> BObjects { get; set; }

        [OneToOne("O2OClassAKey")]
        public ClassB BObject { get; set; }

        // Other properties
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
        
    public class ClassB
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof (ClassA))]
        public int O2MClassAKey { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(typeof (ClassA))]
        public int O2OClassAKey { get; set; }

        // Other properties
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @redent84 , this is exactly what I was looking for. I am just not much sure about what do you mean by "the foreign key for the oneToMany relationship can be declared in any of the classes".

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I meant to say the `OneToOne` property. The foreign key of a one-to-one relationship can be in any of the two ends.

Comment: A couple of things to keep in mind with this:

1. When you insert a row with a relationship, you MUST call `.UpdateWithChildren` for the relationships to be updated in the database.  I fought this for hours trying to figure out why all of my relationships are being stored as _null_.

2. Don't forget your `CascadeOperations` and `ReadOnly` tags if needed.

Comment: @JLWest yes, you have to `InsertWithChildren` or `UpdateWithChildren` after insertion to update relationships.

Comment: @redent84 In my experience `InsertWithChildren` or `InsertOrReplaceWithChildren` will not update the relationships correctly in the database.  All of my relationships were null until I called `UpdateWithChildren`

Comment: what about a OneToOne with the same entity ?