# How to write a simple OneToOne relationship?

Tags: c#, sqlite-net

I would like to write a simple one-to-one relationship between my models.
The exception message I get from `sqlite-net` is `Don't know about Profile`.

```
public class User
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int pk { get; set; }

    public string first_name { get; set;}

    [OneToOne]
    public Profile profile { get; set;}

     ...
}

public class Profile
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int pk { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(User))]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [OneToOne]
    public User user { get; set;}
}
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks

Comment: Why UserId is a `string` when your User pk is `int `

Comment: It doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs), that exception is being thrown on line 2044. If you examine the function you'll see that it's checking whether the C# type is supported and then returning the relevant SQL type.

The Profile type you are trying to add this to is not supported as it is a custom type you have created and so sqlite-net cannot know what SQL type to return for it.

Try and redesign your code so that the OneToOne relationship is only needed on supported types.

Comment: Thanks! Can't I have `sqlite` create a relation table automatically?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not an expert in this area, but it looks like from the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29005182/6017401) that there may be a way to do what you require.